# Hardening a financially critical Windows computer

Tags: windows, security, windows-xp, malware

One of the risks to small and medium businesses is losing your bank credentials to bad guys by use of a key logger or other malware as [Bruce Schneier blogs about](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/08/small_business.html).  A particular threat is [real-time key loggers as described in the NY Times](http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2009/08/20/how-hackers-snatch-real-time-security-id-numbers/).  The bottom line is that with commercial bank login information, bad guys can wire money out of your accounts and there may be no recourse.  Commercial bank account logins are truly the keys to the kingdom.

I’ve decided to substantially increase the security on the machines where these bank credentials are used.  My standard security recommendations are Windows XP SP3 with patches being applied automatically nightly.  Virus protection is on (We generally use ESET).  Users are Limited users; they can’t add software.  Software restrictions prevent the user from accidently or deliberately downloading software and running it out of their user directory.  We use IE8 because of the ease of managing it in a Active Directory environment, but I recognize this as a potential weakness. Unfortunately, the most likely vector of a zero day exploit is flash or acrobat, both of which we use.

Security is always a tradeoff of convenience versus safety, so answers and suggestions should give pros and cons.  I’m going to answer with a few suggestions, so you can see where my thoughts are going.

Comment: I'd rather bug the bank to disable the feature, send me a keyfob that generates real time passwords, or find another bank.  HSBC in Australia and Fortis in Belgium uses keyfobs at no charge to the customer and on ordinary consumer accounts noless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could setup another PC with Linux/BSD on it that is only used for accessing the bank web site.  If you really wanted to get paranoid you could put it on its own dedicated Internet connection and not have anything else connected to it on the regular network.  Gives you the benefits similar to dual boot while still keeping the Windows PC available for other tasks.  Downside is additional hardware/software to maintain.  There's always the possibility that some nefarious employee could put an [inline hardware USB keylogger](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/usb-hardware-keyloggers-1-keycarbon) between the keyboard and the computer regardless of what/how you secure the operating system and software.

Comment: Great suggestions.  Good point about the physical security of hardware keyloggers.

Comment: Have the computer keyboard plug into the front of the PC so it's easy to monitor and see if something changes.

Answer (score 4):

As with all things a risk based approach is going to be best, and the *degree* to which you take this is going to be based on your budget, risk, time, and the potential damage of a breach.  I certainly don't expect you to do everything here.

Here are some of the attack vectors:

**Physical attacks**

Types of attacks

- Theft
- Offline Attacks
- Hardware Key loggers
- Attacker trying to install malware locally
- Shoulder surfing

This is the space where you are going to focus on controlling things related to physical access:

- Auto-locking screens, good passwords (that are not stored under a keyboard), and disk encryption will help when a system is stolen
- Disabling USB ports in the OS or cementing them closed, and disabling autorun can help (but not fully prevent keyloggers)
- Good physical security of the system (good door locks, sturdy computer cabinets, computer locks, occasional audits)
- Privacy screens and keeping systems away from windows help prevent shoulder surfing

**Software Attacks**

- Internet malware
- Social Engineering (Phishing)

Once you put a system on the network you have a world of fun to prevent you from loosing control.

- VM or dual boot scenarios can help separate critical and commonplace information (one system for critical banking one for email)
- It's worth considering a completely seperate box for this sort of thing too if reasonable
- Either way though, you'll need non-priviliged access for users
- Good passwords for all users
- Effective vulnerability management (Patching, Removal of unnecessary services, etc.)
- Security lockdown (Windows has their [Security Guides and Accelerators](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=A3D1BBED-7F35-4E72-BFB5-B84A526C1565&displaylang=en)* there are various guides to *Nix BSD lockdown out there)
- Working and well configured network *AND* local firewalls

*I just set up a Specialized Security Limited Functionality Workstation and it seems to be doing all right.

**Network Attacks**

In addition to hardening the machine you should also have strong transport protections:

- Packet Sniffing
- DNS attacks/SSL MITM attacks
- etc.

Things you can do at this level:

- Transport protections (IPSec on Windows, SSH on *Nix, SSL for web***)
- Well configured and monitored network infrastructure (no default passwords, etc.)
- Don't send sensitve data over wireless***
- Consider network segregation of privileged and non-privileged systems

***SSL attacks are a dime a dozen these days, they are all still essentially MITM (as of this writing) so you should take steps to protect against MITM

***And if you must use wireless, don't use anything less than WPA2-Enterprise

Comment: Very comprehensive advice.

Answer (score 3):

Check your bank's authentication mechanisms!  Mine adds a pseudo-RSA token in the form of a "code card", and most transactions - aside from viewing balances and moving money between my own accounts - require me to input a randomly selected number from the 100 printed on that card.  Each code can only be used once, and when they're all gone I get a new card.  This satisfies the "something you know and something you have" requirement of dual-factor without the overhead of issuing all users with a real RSA token, and that's just for a personal account.  If your bank won't give you a decent level of security beyond this for a business account, ditch it and find one that will!

Comment: Unfortunately, our bank isn't so sophisticated.  While I can mandate most security processes, it would take more political capital than I can draw on to changes banks.  That's a great system they have and I wish ours had it.  Also note that the NY times article addresses how RSA tokens can be attacked with real time malware.

Comment: That's unfortunate about your bank. When ours introduced it for business accounts I thought it was a real PITA - having to carry around a stupid RSA keyfob. After reading these responses though I'm kind of glad now.

Answer (score 1):

Stop surfing the net from that machine.  Don't check email, don't go to websites outside of your LAN, etc.  Do all of that on some other machine, then post what you need to do from the financial computer in a local wiki (or something).  Don't use the financial machine as a file server, print server, etc etc etc.

Costs: a $500 Dell to surf from
Benefits: Your data is more safe.

I would also invest in a firewall (hardware, not software) to put in front of the machine.  Don't let anything in, and make policies out of the above, instead of trusting users to do the right thing.

Comment: A software firewall is still important, because if something *does* manage to get inside the network, it may very well stop it from sending data *outside* the network.

Comment: I meant directly in front of the machine, not for the network.  You should already have one of those.

Comment: And, hardware firewalls can keep things from getting out.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to Vista x64.  Seriously.  It's a lot harder to exploit reliably.

That doesn't stop malware that your users run (by going to websites, etc etc), but it stops network-based attacks that you won't have much detection of.

Comment: It would be nice to see some supporting links for this statement.

Comment: My source is, unfortunately, people I know who write exploits.  I don't have links to in-person discussion :)

Comment: UAC helps a lot, though users should have limited privs in any event.  I'd trust Vista/7 in an instant over XP.

Comment: Sorry if I don't take your word for it- I would have a hard time basing a business decision (like the OP is doing) on personal stories.

Comment: I'm sorry, are you suggesting that I'm basing my decisions on personal stories?

Comment: @ Knox: Re-reading my comment, I see now that it can come across as you pointed out.  This was not my intention. I was trying to point out to Weiss that it is not the best idea to  build a business case based off of a personal story (in this case, that Vista x64 is seriously harder to exploit than 32bit) I was not saying that this is what you were doing.  Sorry about the miscommunication.

Comment: Ok, here are some points for x64 vs 32-bit.  Thanks for pushing me to qualify my statements :)

Hardware enforced NX and DEP (32-bit machines might have this if they're on certain processors, and they're configured correctly, maybe).  This is protection against buffer overflows, and it raises the bar of difficulty for them. Source: Microsoft http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms791539.aspx

PatchGuard/Kernel Patch Protection, along with required signing of drivers. This makes it harder for malware to evade detection.

It's not bulletproof, but every bit helps, right?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the number of transactions these people have to do you may opt for a diskless workstation for banking transactions ONLY. 
Diskless immediately implies booting from a read only medium like a CDROM.
Something like a stripped CDROM bootable Linux that only the bare minimum of software (i.e. only a webbrowser) may be a valid option for this kind of work.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to specific host protection techniques, look for defense in depth approaches to this. For instance, most web filtering software will block known bad sites. If one of your users hits one early on, that's not going to help, but once one is discovered, it makes it into the filtering lists fairly quickly. Along those same lines, look at external DNS solutions like [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) which perform a similar function, but without the web filtering software/appliance requirement. On your firewall, perform egress filtering. Block the known ports for IRC, etc. No, this won't stop a piece of malware that uses a custom port, but many do not. Hopefully, you're web filtering solution helps with those which do use something custom. Also, consider implementing IDS/IPS. If money is tight, there is always [Snort](http://www.snort.org/).

Comment: We use OpenDNS for our entire enterprise with a number of categories blocked.  For me, that's standard.

Answer (score 0):

Move to 64bit Windows 7 since malware is very rarely targeting 64bit code yet.  Pro’s are less viruses; con’s are that we have to get new 64bit hardware and deal with various incompatibilities.  [XP mode may be needed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XP_Mode#Windows_XP_Mode).

Comment: Is this really true? If so, that's a useful thing to bear in mind.

Comment: I think it's true, but with caveats.  I can imagine that 32 bit malware could install itself somewhere and then schedule itself to run using some scheduled task,  (It'd be running under the 32 bit WOW subsystem) but it very difficult for it to become a rootkit in 64bit windows.  This type of malware would be a lot easier for a virus scanner to find.  Of course, what the bad guys target today will be different in 5 years.  Maybe then I'll be recommending 128bit windows  :)

Comment: Your chances are better if you don't disable UAC too...

Comment: I would not rely on this at all - 32bit viruses can infect a 64bit operating system and potentially harm it. Check out this whitepaper from Symantec: http://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/enterprise/media/security_response/whitepapers/32bit_virus_threats_on_64bit_windows.pdf

Comment: @MattB, thank you for the resource; I'll read that and perhaps withdraw this suggestion.

Comment: @Rowland, I personally increase the UAC on Windows 7 to the highest level.

Comment: The worst advise ever. Win 7 being 64 bit does not mean the 32 bit malware won't run.

Comment: 64 bit Windows can run 32 bit code - even games - very well; this will accomplish virtually nothing.

Comment: +1 because the UAC alone will help immensely and there is virtually no added cost to 64-bit systems.  The comments on 32/64 and virii are all true, but don't seem particularly relevant since one has to tighten the security bolts anyway 32 or 64.

Answer (score 0):

Force the users to dual boot into some other OS (BSD?) when doing bank activity.  Pro’s:  Very safe.  Con:  very inconvenient since they won’t have access to various windows app’s for figuring out who and how much to wire to.

Comment: -1 (sorry) because the dual boot is problematic for users (who will not be familiar with this, or will get it wrong, boot into the wrong machine to use, etc.)  And a problem for *you*:  Where's your auditing;  you can't control the boot and it still goes across your network to your routers, to the cloud, etc., whether it's secure or not.

Comment: Another point that should have been in comment (sorry again):  The OP mentioned he was in an AD environment.  That is not designed to have a machine drop in as Windows, reboot, and drop out, and back in as a BSD or Linux client (I'm presuming the use of Samba or another LDAP solution.)  **Think of the users!  Make it easy for them to stay safe!**

Comment: Because there's a very small number of users with these financially critical machines, if I set up a second machine, or dual boot to a second operating system, I won't be using AD...  but then I will start having to worry about passwords, etc.  It's pretty inconvenient for both users and network management to have a second operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Use disk encryption. Whatever you do in the OS, as long as you can boot a CD and access the filesystem outside of Windows you're not safe. WinVista/Win7 has encryption capability built-in, but there are heaps of WinXP-capable 3rd party solutions as well.

Look into NAP-type policies where the computer doesn't get internet access before it's patched to company standards (if you need them to have internet access, that is).

Look into Desktop Virtualization (both MS and VMWare have solutions for this) to isolate the bank apps into it's own, tightly managed environment.

Just my 5 cents...

Comment: Disk encryption does not stop key loggers!

Comment: I'm aware of that. The question was security threats in general, with keyloggers as one particular threat.

Answer (score 0):

Use VMWare with a basic linux guest to do all online banking but run it on the computer with all the accounting software so you can easily switch between host and guest to view necessary data.

Comment: unfortunately I think that if the host, being windows, gets infected by a key logger, that all of the keystrokes going to the linux VM will be seen by the bad guys.

Answer (score 0):

The NSA and Microsoft came up with the original security guides. The documents are rather long and I'd recommend testing the settings out on a computer you can reformat as it is quite possible to lock things down so much that the only cure is to boot from a cd/dvd and wipe the drive.

http://csrc.nist.gov/itsec/guidance_WinXP.html

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc163140.aspx

I agree with your idea that flash/acrobat are the likeliest threats. Limiting user rights is the largest step in securing the computer that I can think of.

Disable autorun for all computers in the gpedit.msc. Some of the banks I've worked at would disable USB ports. There are now applications that can monitor them and only allow permitted connections. The older banks would use hot-melt glue to seal the ports and prevent plugging things in (one bank used locks on the floppy drives, and would fire anyone on the spot who's {cheap} lock fell out). There are a number of articles where researchers drop USB thumb drives in parking lots near offices and see how many get plugged into computers at the office - the install ended up just sending the IP address home - more malevolent installers have used the icon that one sees for "open with explorer" tricking the user into not paying attention, so they click the installer.

Comment: Good advice.  I did not try to list most of the security features that we use for all users, but we do much of what you suggest:  USB autorun locked down by Active Directory, all limited users, software restrictions to prevent exe's from running on flash drives, etc.